# strstr on huge mmapped file

Tags: c, string, mmap

I open huge (11Gb) file, mmap it to memmory, and fail to search the string in the file

my code is

```
 if ( (fd  = open("l", O_RDONLY)) < 0 )     err_sys("Cant open file");
 if ( fstat(fd, &statbuf) < 0 )             err_sys("Cant get file size");
 printf("size is %ld\n", statbuf.st_size);

 if ( (src = mmap(0, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED )  err_sys("Cant mmap");
 printf("src pointer is at %ld\n", src);

 char * index = strstr(src, "bin/bash");
 printf("needle is at %ld\n", index);
```

It works on small files, but on huge sources returns 0. What function should I use to search in huge mmapped files?

The output is:

```
size is 11111745740
src pointer is at 140357526544384
needle is at 0
```

Comment: Are you sure the file contains `"bin/bash"` at all?

Comment: Are you compiling your program as a 32 bit program? Have you enabled large file support? What operating system are you programming for? What does "fail" mean? If one of the system calls failed, what was the value of `errno` afterwards? Please provide us with that information.

Comment: Also, `%ld` is not the right formatting specifier to print a pointer  and neither is it for `off_t`.

Comment: Are you sure the input file doesn't contain any null bytes? Because these would make `strstr` stop. If you could give us more details, it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: @fuz: What does this have to do with `double`? It's `void*` for `"%p"` if you want to `printf()` a pointer.

Comment: @EOF Sorry, I meant pointer, no idea why I wrote `double`.

Comment: What @fuz said. If it's binary data, you can't generally get away with using `strstr` on it.  See if you have the `memmem` function available.

Comment: Note also that a `mmap()` of the exact number of bytes in a file won't NUL-terminate the data if the file is an exact multiple of the page size being used.

Comment: Combining a fix for the possibility of `\0` *in* the file and lack of it at the *end* of the file would be to `memmem()` instead of `strstr()` if GNU extensions are available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use `strstr()` to search for text in a memory mapped file:

- If the file is binary, it most likely contains null bytes that will stop the search too soon. This is probably what you observe.
- If the file is pure text, but does not contain a match, `strstr` will keep scanning beyond the end of the file, invoking undefined behavior by attempting to read unmapped memory.

You could instead use a function with equivalent semantics but applied to raw memory instead of C strings, `memmem()`, available on Linux and BSD systems:

```
void *memmem(const void *p1, size_t size1, const void *p2, size_t size2);
```

Note that you also use the wrong `printf` formats: it should be `%p` for `src` and `index` and you might prefer to print the offset as a `ptrdiff_t` or an `unsigned long long`:

```
    if ((fd  = open("l", O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        err_sys("Cannot open file");
    if (fstat(fd, &statbuf) < 0)
        err_sys("Cannot get file size");

    printf("size is %llu\n", (unsigned long long)statbuf.st_size);

    if ((src = mmap(0, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        err_sys("Cannot mmap");

    printf("src pointer is at %p\n", (void*)src);

    char *index = memmem(src, statbuf.st_size, "bin/bash", strlen("bin/bash"));
    printf("needle is at %p\n", (void*)index);

    if (index != NULL)
        printf("needle is at offset %llu\n", (unsigned long long)(index - src));
```

If `memmem` is not available on your platform, here is a simple implementation:

```
#include <string.h>

void *memmem(const void *haystack, size_t n1, const void *needle, size_t n2) {
    const unsigned char *p1 = haystack;
    const unsigned char *p2 = needle;

    if (n2 == 0)
        return (void*)p1;
    if (n2 > n1)
        return NULL;

    const unsigned char *p3 = p1 + n1 - n2 + 1;
    for (const unsigned char *p = p1; (p = memchr(p, *p2, p3 - p)) != NULL; p++) {
        if (!memcmp(p, p2, n2))
            return (void*)p;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for Linux and BSD function [`memmem()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmem.3.html)?  It isn't specified in POSIX, and doesn't appear to be provided on Windows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: indeed this function is available on some but not all unix systems. The C Standard has `memchr()`, `memcpy()`, `memcmp()`, `memmove()`... it would make sense to include `memmem()` and some other useful Posix functions such as `strdup()`, `getline()`, etc.